# EntityFramework Code First with strongly typed tables and dynamic table names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dynamic-tables

I'm trying to create an application that creates tables on runtime with the same structure but  different table names.
Different jobs will collect data and every job should get his own table, because every job will collect more than 10 million entries and I don't want to store them within one table.
The type of the stored entries is identical for each job, but every table should be named with the job name.
In the end I won't to do something like this:

```
JobResultType result001 = context.Table("JobResults001").Where(...); 
List<JobResultType> results002 = context.Table("JobResults002").Where(...).ToList();
...
```

I tried already EntityFramework Code First and Linq2SQL and got no working solution.

Is there somebody who knows a lightweight and clean solution to this problem?

The solution should work with SQL Server and MySql ;-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In EF, you can use fluent mappings to control the table names that the data comes from:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobResultsType>()
    .ToTable("JobResults0001");
```

So, perhaps you can create a different context or re-run the fluent mappings for the different jobs? So a job comes in, and then you create a new context that uses the new table names to map to... I think that *should* work...